# How to remove parental control on Amazon Kindle

Tags: amazon-kindle-fire, parental-control

I have an Amazon Kindle Fire HD with parental control, but I have forgotten the code.

How can I remove it without losing anything?

I think it involves some kind of "reset", but I want to be sure I won't lose something from the device before I start and that I won’t have to spend a lot of time re-sending stuff to it.

I see something about de-registering, so perhaps it is not so difficult, though when I try to do it, parental control is blocking me, also it is blocking me from connecting to the Internet with Wi-Fi.

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2414022
suggest to rename ParentalControls.apk - but I am not able to (seems to be locked).  Also I am not able to find the data-file mentioned.

Comment: @Olav somehow do you want the solution for this or you offering the help for the OP, BTW if you are rooted then you try to delete the data folder of the parental control using root explorer can help you. Another thing on Google i read some people enter their Wifi password and it let get them in, or I read on XDA a user renamed the **parentalcontrols.apk** and **parentalcontrols.odex** to .bak and it doesn't ask for parental control but he can't connect to Wifi after this.

Comment: another thing i can say if you are rooted then use Titanium backup or Go backup to make a backup of your device applications along with data and leave the parentalcontrol app backup and reset it, I don't think it will loose root and then again restore using that tool I have done it many times.

Comment: i thought only parents can do it :)

Comment: If you have Kindle Paperwhite, you can enter 111222777 as the parental controls password, which will trigger a factory reset https://www.lifewire.com/reset-parental-password-kindle-5222250

Answer (score 3):

Look at this [amazon help forum](http://www.amazon.com/forum/kindle?_encoding=UTF8&cdForum=Fx1D7SY3BVSESG&cdThread=TxKB7D5FMDC03Q) about this issue. I found this:

> This is a bug in the kindle. Don't reset your device people!!! Just go onto your amazon account and "manage your device" and deregister it. That resets the parental control password. Go to the device and hit resync. When thats done go into the settings gear, my account, and register it using your amazon account info. It will be as before, nothing lost. I just got off the chat with a helpful amazon tech rep who gave me this information.

Also take a look at this answer on a forum found at [askville.amazon.com](http://askville.amazon.com/reset-parental-controls-password-forgot/AnswerViewer.do?requestId=88814347):

> > If you forget your password, you can deregister your Kindle Fire from Manage Your Kindle (www.amazon.com/manageyourkindle) to reset the
> >     parental controls password. Deregistering your Kindle Fire will also
> >     allow you to keep any downloaded items on your device. Once your
> >     Kindle Fire has been deregistered, tap Sync from the Quick Settings
> >     menu on your device, tap More, then select My Account to reregister
> >     your device.
>
> If you're unable to deregister your Kindle Fire from Manage Your
>   Kindle, you'll need to reset your device to the default factory
>   settings to regain access. If you've added any personal documents,
>   music, videos, or other content to your Kindle Fire, ensure it's been
>   backed up prior to resetting your device. Resetting your Kindle Fire
>   to the default factory settings will delete all content on your device
>   and you'll need to register it again before downloading items from
>   your Amazon account.
>
> To reset your device to the default factory settings:
>
> K6:
>
> 1. Tap the Quick Settings icon in the top right corner of the screen, then tap More.
> 2. Tap Device, then tap Reset to Factory Defaults.
>
> K9 / K9-HD / K10:
>
> 1. Swipe down from the top of the screen, then tap More.
> 2. Tap Device, then tap Reset to Factory Defaults.
>
> To ensure your Kindle Fire has the latest software update, visit:
>
> http://www.amazon.com/kindlesoftwareupdates
>
> Kindle Fire also supports Parental Controls for in-app items purchased
>   through the Amazon Appstore.

Answer (score 1):

Try out these links:

- [How to Undo Parental Controls on a Kindle Fire](http://everydaylife.globalpost.com/undo-parental-controls-kindle-fire-26179.html)
- [Kindle Support](http://www.kindle.com/support)

Factory reset is the on more option. You will lose your data, so back-up your data before resetting.

Comment: The first link just explains how to disable Parental Controls *if you already know the code*. It also says "If you forgot your Parental Controls password, you'll have to reset the device". So that link doesn't provide a suitable answer. The second link is just a generic link to Kindle's support page.

Answer (score 1):

You could just try de-registering your Kindle from your Amazon-Account and you may get rid of the password. Note that that WILL delete all Amazon content (like books, apps and so on) but it should leave other things untouched (like your own photos, music or other stuff you have sideloaded to your device). You would de-register it at Manage Your Devices on Amazon. After re-registering you should be able to download all your content from Amazon again, including books, apps and so on.

Answer found here: [Yahoo Answers](http://au.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20131112030746AAFhcHC)

Comment: no (see question)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't seem to find the answer to this question on one of Amazon's FAQ sites and/or the in the instruction manual, back up your data and do a factory reset. It's also the quickest way than rather run around in circles, but be careful, that data could have some stuff that you can't afford to lose (like my "Flappy Bird" high score).

Answer (score 0):

My son's Kindle Fire HD 2014 had the same problem with the parental controls password.  Somehow the Kindle went offline and I couldn't turn WiFi on and the password was not working. I de-registered it directly on the Kindle since it was not online. Then I registered it again and everything is back on his Kindle. I was concerned he was going to lose the level he was on on all his games but he didn't!

So, do not reset back to factory settings because you will loose everything. Just de-register and register again.